# Input function in SAS

Tags: sas

I have an output data set as shown below.

`data test;
input date$ sales;
cards;
NOV2016 23
DEC2016 24
run;`

I need a output data set from the above data as

```
NOV2016 23 01-nov-2016
DEC2016 24 01-Dec-2016
```

To create this, I am using the code as below, but it is not working. Please suggest any workaround for this problem.

```
data test1;
set test;
newdate=input(date, monyy.);
format newdate date9.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default W for MONYYw is 5, you need to specify the proper width.

```
new_date = input(date,monyy7.);
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/69823/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0720b1ks40htdn1s09vs9a0kr6m.htm